# Use variable key in CasperJS' fillSelectors

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I want to use a variable as key for the `fillSelectors()` Method input tag:

```
this.fillSelectors(formLogin, { variable1:myEmail},false)
```

The form name and the value (myEmail) are variable, but not the key(variable1). As key, a string is needed, otherwise I get an error:

```
 CasperError: Errors encountered while filling form: no field matching css selector "inpu1" in form
```

Can you help with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By doing `{ variable1: myEmail }` you are creating an object with a property named `variable1`. This is exactly the same as `{ "variable1": myEmail }` because in javascript keys are read as strings every time. This is different from other languages like python where you can have different objects as keys not just strings.

What you want is to build your object differently:

```
var obj = {};
obj[variable1] = myEmail; // here the value of variable1 is used, not its name
this.fillSelectors(formLogin, obj, false)
```

Comment: Now I can have all three pieces (form id, key and value fields) dynamic.